Stability Index Forms an Open Set
Let the ODE
$$x' = A(x),$$ where A is an linear vector field on $\mathbb{R}^d$, denote this set by $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. We say that $A$ is hiperbolic if A does not have pure imaginary eigenvalue, i.e., $sp(A) \cap i \mathbb{R} = \emptyset$; denote by $H(\mathbb{R}^d)$ the set of hiperbolic linear vector fields. I already have shown that $H(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is open and dense in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
Now, for $A \in H(\mathbb{R}^d)$, define the stability index s(A) as the number (counting the respective multiplicity) of the eigenvalues of A with negative real part.
For fixed $k \in \{1,\, \dots \,, d\}$, I want to show that
$$ \{ A \in H(\mathbb{R}^d) \, ; \, s(A) = k\}$$
is open in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
My attempt was to repeat the argument that shows $H(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is open, but I get nowhere. Any ideas?
Thanks.

take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231500/lie-bracket-of-linear-vector-field
